# ServiceFabric - ApplicationManifest.xml - RepositoryCredentials to use ACR Service Connection

Tags: azure, azure-devops, manifest, serviceconnection, acr

I have a Service Fabric application that downloads the image from Azure ACR repostiry.  The authentication of the ACR repo is from ApplicationManifest.xml

```
 <RepositoryCredentials AccountName="{AccountName}" Password="{Password}" PasswordEncrypted="false" />
```

Would like to know is there any possible way to use Azure DevOps ACR Service connection in `"RepositoryCredentials ..."`

As per [Microsoft document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/configure-container-repository-credentials) we can use Accountname and Password (or) token registry credentials to download the ACR image

Answer (score 0):

Azure DevOps Service connection is used in azure devops pipeline tasks. It is designed to allows you to connect to the external and remote services in azure devops pipeline.

I am afraid it cannot be used in `RepositoryCredentials` of Service Fabric's ApplicationManifest.xml.

See [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#use-connection) for more information about azure devops service connection.

Comment: We can't use Azure DevOps Service Connection in this scenario.